# Do you need <something> formal form

Tags: translation

Is the following translation of the sentence "Do you need " correct?

For example

1. 네가 영수증을 필요습니까? (do you need a receipt? formal)
2. 네가 쟁반을 필요습니까? (do you need a tray? formal)

Can you point out the mistakes?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Formal forms of these sentences are

영수증이 필요하십니까?
and
쟁반이 필요하십니까?

1. '네가' should be '당신이' to be more polite, but omitting the subjects sounds more natural.
2. 필요습니까 does not make sense syntactically. The verb is 필요하다 or 필요로 하다.
3. In these cases, making 쟁반 as an object is not very natural.
   Instead, double-subject sentence (이중주어문) is better choice.

e.g. 당신은 쟁반이 필요합니까? / 당신은 쟁반이 필요하십니까?
is a double-subject sentence. 당신 and 쟁반 are both subjects of the sentence.
당신 is omitted, so the final form is '쟁반이 필요하십니까?'

Reference: [이중주어문](https://encykorea.aks.ac.kr/Article/E0079630)